# PHP Script or Cron Job to Load Pages from XML SiteMap (For Caching Purposes)

Tags: php, caching, cron

I am trying to determine how I want to tackle this... this is all new to me.  My site (I did not build it) has caching in place but a page only caches if it is visited.

What I was thinking is that if I have an xml sitemap with all my pages, use that as a check list and have a script load (or "visit") those pages to cache them once a day.

Is this even possible?  Has anyone here done something similar? As you might be able to tell, I am kinda new at PHP...

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.  Ideas, steps, functions, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but why? It sounds to me as if you have a problem with cache pruning; but cache pruning is a good thing. The pages will be cached when they are visited, and if they aren't visited, bringing them into the cache is just a waste of space and cycles.

Comment: The pages initially take a long time to load and I don't want to loose a visitor to a page not loading quickly

Comment: The curse of caching… Tell whoever made the site to get on the ball and speed up the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that if you properly code your site (mysql queries specifically), correctly and efficiently, there is no need to have caching in place.  I spent a few days re-writing the functions and queries that do the same thing but don't create unwanted lag and unnecessary queries.

If anyone else is having similar issues, I urge you to optimize your code... ask for help if you need but you shouldn't have to cache a site unless it requires a ton of queries per page load and the page doesn't change daily.